# Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, rest, localhost

I'm trying to call a webservice from my local machine. But the I get the following errors in Chrome console:
`http://www.test.com/service.svc/api/?cid=1 405 (Method Not Allowed) 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.test.com/service.svc/api/?cid=1.

Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

My local test URL is: 
`http://localhost/welcome/html/index.html`

When I upload my code to the actual domain and call the webservice from there, it does work ofcourse.

I've already tried to change the access control headers, but that doesnt help.

```
Namespace RestService

Public Class service
    Implements Iservice

    Public Function GetProvinces(ByVal cid As String) As AjaxControlToolkit.CascadingDropDownNameValue() Implements Iweddingservice.GetProvinces
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "DELETE, POST, GET, OPTIONS")
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")

        Dim MyConnection As SqlConnection = GetConnection()
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT provinceid,title FROM provinces WHERE CountryID=@CountryID ORDER BY title ASC", MyConnection)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@CountryID", cid))
        Dim values As New List(Of CascadingDropDownNameValue)
        Try
            MyConnection.Open()
            Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            While reader.Read
                values.Add(New CascadingDropDownNameValue(reader("title").ToString, reader("provinceid").ToString))
            End While
        Catch ex As Exception

        Finally
            MyConnection.Close()
        End Try
        Return values.ToArray
    End Function

End Class


End Namespace
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The request to the service is failing because of browser [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Your local server is at `http://localhost` while you are trying to access a resource at http://www.test.com/. These are both at different domains. So it won't work.

The solution to this problem is to use the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`, part of the [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) spec. You've included these in the response headers but that won't do any good because the browser will be making a pre-flight request with OPTIONS verb to verify if the call is allowed. Since your service is not able to handle the OPTIONS verb you are seeing a 405 (Method Not Allowed) error.

So, if you'd want your service to be accessible from a different domain then you'll have to modify your WCF service to support CORS. I would recommend this link: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/idof/archive/2011/07/02/cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-and-wcf.aspx. By using this you can make your service support CORS with no change in your existing code.